# CRect member variables have strange values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to use the member variables from my client rect, but they are holding extremely negative values, like -858993460.  Even when I call rect.Width(), it returns an extremely negative number.  I need the values to determine the corresponding section of a wave file to play when I select the wave that I have drawn on the screen. Would anyone happen to know why it could be doing this?

Note: I threw int's right, left, and width in just to see what values they are holding. I really only need rect.Width() to scale the selection to be able to access the data array of my wave file.

```
void CWaveEditView::OnToolsPlay32775()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CWaveEditDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if(!pDoc){
        return;
    }
    if(pDoc->wave.hdr==NULL){
        return;
    }
    if(selectionStart!=selectionEnd){
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        rect.NormalizeRect();
        int right = rect.right;
        int left = rect.left;
        int width = rect.Width();
        int startms=(1000.0*pDoc->wave.lastSample/pDoc->wave.sampleRate)*selectionStart/rect.Width();
        int endms=(1000.0*pDoc->wave.lastSample/pDoc->wave.sampleRate)*selectionEnd/rect.Width();
        WaveFile * selection = new WaveFile(pDoc->wave.numChannels, pDoc->wave.sampleRate, pDoc->wave.bitsPerSample);

        while(startms<=endms){
            selection->add_sample(pDoc->wave.get_sample(startms));
            startms++;
        }
        selection->updateHeader();
        selection->play();
        delete selection;
    }
```

Comment: -858993460 is 0xCCCCCCCC, which is the debugger's way of saying "uninitialized variable". My guess is `GetClientRect` call fails for some reason, and leaves `rect` uninitialized. Perhaps your view doesn't have a valid `HWND` at this point, somehow.

Comment: Do you know what would cause that?  My view is working properly, as it draws everything it is supposed to.

Comment: Well, you could start by checking the return value of `GetClientRect`, and if it fails, checking the reason with `GetLastError`.

Comment: I'm using mfc, so GetClientRect doesn't return anything unfortunately.  I was able to grab the error message though, and it came up with 0xcccccccc <Bad Ptr>.  Should CRect rect actually be CRect * rect?  I'm just starting to learn MFC so I apologize if this is something basic

Comment: Also, what would cause GetCliectRect() to fail?

Comment: Check the m_hWnd member, and try the ::GetClientRect Win32 APIs

Comment: I just figured it out, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor of CRect does not initialise its members (because it is a thin wrapper for the RECT structure). You could initialise it to (0,0,0,0) and check whether or not it is empty after your call to GetClientRect.

Since GetClientRect appears to be failing, you may want to check that your window handle is valid using GetSafeHwnd().

Comment: Just a note: As of Visual Studio 2013, the default constructor of `CRect` actually initializes its members to zero. Documentation is still incorrect (even the VS2017 documentation) but a look into the source (atltypes.h) proves that `CRect::CRect()` sets all members to zero.